# How to externally execute a .mel script file into the current scene rather than open a new maya window?

Tags: maya, mel

I have been learning scripting in Maya and so far so good.

One thing I would like to do is execute very simple  `.mel` script files externally, with the goal of them changing something in a existing maya window. Very similar to how [THIS](https://github.com/artbycrunk/vscode-maya) VSCode extension for Maya Mel script works.
Here is a video example of the extension:
[image]

I want to use this with AutoHotkey, a programming language suited for keyboard and mouse automation, to do something like:

```
Capslock & f::  ; when Capslock and f are pressed run the mel file "c:\temp\Layout4.mel". Which will change the active maya layout
Run, c:\temp\Layout4.mel
```

I know I can assign the above function to a keyboard key internally in maya. I have done that and I am now finding it to be limited. I do this with many other software's such as adobe Illustrator and Photoshop which let you execute arbitrary code in `.jsx` files externally, which will have an affect on the open document.

The few things I have tried while a maya window is open are:

- Double clicking a `.mel` script file in file explorer
- in PowerShell invoking `Maya 'c:\temp\Layout4.mel'`
- in PowerShell invoking `Maya -script 'c:\temp\Layout4.mel'`
- in PowerShell invoking `Maya -command 'c:\temp\Layout4.mel'`
  All of the above just lead to the creation of a new maya window that eventually open a new empty scene.

the only thing that worked was dragging `c:\temp\Layout4.mel` and dropping onto a maya window. The current  layout instantly changes to 'Layout4'. Thats what I want but rather than drag and drop, just executing `.mel` file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you are after the `source` MEL command? _(which allows you to execute an external MEL file)_. If you want to execute Maya from the command line, and have it execute within a specific file, issue a `file` command first to load the specific scene, then source your script.